# Molotov-Ribbentrop pact - Where was Hitler?

Tags: world-war-two

Why didn't Hitler attend the negotiations of the pact in August 1939, but Stalin did?

He was afraid of being assassinated by the Soviets or what?

Comment: Neither Stalin nor Hitler (while in power) ever visited a country unoccupied by their respective armies. After MR pact, negotiations between USSR and Germany continued with Molotov visiting Berlin (Fall of 1940). Stalin, of course, did not come.

Comment: It's not anything out of the ordinary for a leader to not negotiate in person in another country. Do you have any reason to think Hitler would've gone to the USSR?

Comment: Furthermore, moving your leader around doesn't help to keep secret negotiacions secret.

Comment: @Semaphore: In fact, several times he did, he even had his temporary headquarters during WW2, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werwolf_(Wehrmacht_headquarters)). Of course, only territories under Nazi occupation.

Comment: @MoisheKohan which is obviously not the same as going to the Soviet government for in person negotiations

Comment: @MoisheKohan Hitler did. France in WWI.

Comment: @Gangnus The part unoccupied by German army?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Don't change your position during the discussion, without admitting you are wrong! You said COUNTRY, not PART of it. :-)

Comment: @Gangnus Just read my other comment above.

Comment: @MoisheKohan "only Nazi occupation" cannot be applied to WWI, too. Can you EXACTLY formulate what you want to say? The whole thought, please.

Comment: I do not understand why the question was downvoted. The question can have an exact answer and it does have it.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Hitler visited Italy, for example, in 1938. https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0022009407075544

Comment: @Gangnus: This trip to Italy is a good example, which means I was wrong in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the pact was subscribed by ministers only. It was not made on the level of the heads of the states. Hitler and Stalin were not demanded to be present.

Stalin visited the final of the subscription only as a "polite host". Hitler naturally remained at home.

Hitler was not personally a coward. A messenger at the first lines of WWI could not be. Stalin was. He never visited the war.